# How to name routes, templates and views in Ember with Router v2.1?

Tags: ember.js

The routing API has been changed ("v2.1"), again. I have problems adjusting my code to the latest changes. Here is my routing:

```
App.Router.map(function(match) {
  (match("/")).to("index");
  (match("/project")).to("project", function(match) {
    (match("/settings")).to("setup", function(match) {
      (match("/basics")).to("basics");
    });
  });
  (match("/user")).to("user", function(match) {
    (match("/settings")).to("setup", function(match) {
      (match("/basics")).to("basics");
    });
  });
});
```

**How should the templates, routes and views be called here?**

The complete editable code can be found under http://jsfiddle.net/stephanos/mgp7F/20/.

**EDIT**

I had an old version of EmberJS still in there, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/stephanos/mgp7F/26/

Comment: do you have an actual template named "index" / the jsfiddle didn't load up for me btw

Comment: there is an error: route not found - because I don't know how to name it...

Comment: please note: Version #26 of the jsfiddle now contains the latest version of Ember.js

Comment: just curious -why the extra set of ( around each match ?

Comment: my code is in Coffeescript and that's what `coffee` returned :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your {{#linkTo}} helpers need to follow the child.parent naming convention.

So in the example change to :-

```
{{#linkTo projectSetup.basics}}User Settings{{/linkTo}}
{{#linkTo userSetup.basics}}Project Settings{{/linkTo}}
```